# findAllByCreator don't work on custom rpc or mainet-beta

Tags: metaplex

I'm running const nfts = await metaplex.nfts().findAllByCreator({ creator });
the request only works in  devnet: 'https://api.devnet.solana.com/',
but when I change to another rpc it just gives me an empty array instead of the proper answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future travelers, was an issue with the RPC provider, Alchemy, I changed to quicknode and everything goes ok